# How to disable WLDF debug in weblogic 12.1.3?

Tags: weblogic12c

I want to disable the WLDF debug through weblogic console?
I found something to disable diagnostic extension and it is already false for my weblogic.

Through backend I found that the below tag needs to be added in config.xml of the weblogic:

```
<server-diagnostic-config>
  <diagnostic-store-dir>data/store/diagnostics</diagnostic-store-dir>
  <diagnostic-store-file-locking-enabled>false</diagnostic-store-file-locking-enabled>
  <diagnostic-data-archive-type>FileStoreArchive</diagnostic-data-archive-type>
  <data-retirement-enabled>false</data-retirement-enabled>
  <preferred-store-size-limit>100</preferred-store-size-limit>
  <store-size-check-period>1</store-size-check-period>
  <wldf-builtin-system-resource-type>None</wldf-builtin-system-resource-type>
</server-diagnostic-config>
```

Still want to know how to do it from console.

Comment: The above can be found: `Domain > Diagnostics > Built-in Diagnostics Modules > [server] > Built-in Module`. Set it to `None`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I saw it is None by default.